# Lebesgue Covering Lemma Alternate Proof

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

In the book "Functions of of Several Real Variables" by Martin Moskowitz and Fotios Paliogiannis , I came across a theorem titled **"Lebesgue Covering Lemma"**.

The statement of the theorem and its proof given in the textbook is in the "image" embedded below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDEdg.png

Here is my doubt:

Would the following argument work as an alternative proof?

Is there any mistake in the argument below?

""""**We know that each x that belongs to the set S also belongs to the open cover of the S i.e the union of V_i(by the definition of open cover of the set given in the textbook). Thus each x must belong to some V_i . But V_i is already an open set by definition of an open cover. Then we can find an open ball of radius delta for each x belonging to S such that it is a subset for some V_i.(By the definition of an open set)**""""

Please note that I do not have any knowledge in topology than what is already given in this book.

Comment: I have added the image.

Comment: Someone please help.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) has the **correct** statement (your textbook has a wrong version) and a proof too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Lebesgue covering lemma is stated incorrectly in **Lemma** $\bf{1.6.2}$. You’ve proved what is actually asserted, but that’s not the Lebesgue covering lemma. The author inadvertently reversed two quantifiers: it should say that there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in S$, $B_\delta(x)\subseteq V_i$ for at least one $i\in I$. The difference is that the Lebesgue covering lemma says that there is one $\delta$ that works for every $x\in S$; what was actually stated, and what you proved, is that for each $x\in S$ there is a $\delta$ that works, but it need not be the same $\delta$ for all points $x\in S$. It’s a much weaker statement than the actual Lebesgue covering lemma.